# Splitting all words but keeping the split characters

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl I am trying to build an array of all words from a paragraph of text.

Right now I am using `@tokens = split /[^\w']+/, $mytext;`

It seems to be getting all the alphanum words but I want all punctuation to be considered a word to except underscore. Example

`hi. my name is first_last ...`

Should turn into the words: hi , . , my , name , is , first_last , . , . , .

A total of 9 words.

How can I do that? I tried splitting on punctuation but it did not save the punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

It's often easier to match than split; it sounds like you want to match any series of single quote/word characters (including _) or any single other non-whitespace character:

```
my $mytext = 'hi. my name is first_last ...';
my @tokens = $mytext =~ /([\w']+|\S)/g;
print join( ' , ',  @tokens ),"\n";
```

produces:

```
hi , . , my , name , is , first_last , . , . , .
```

`[\w']` is a character class that allows any word character (letters, digits, or underscore) or a single quote; other characters can be added, though some may need to be \-escaped (e.g. `[\w'\-]` to add a hyphen).

Comment: what part of this allows the _ to be in a word? what if I want another character allowed in a word, like a hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

If these are your words

```
hi. my name is first_last ...
11  22 3333 44 5555555555
```

and these aren't your separators

```
hi. my name is first_last ...
  11  22   33 4          5555
```

then you aren't actually splitting words (and `split` probably won't work well). You actually need a tokeniser.

Here's a generic way of building a tokeniser:

```
my @tokens;
for ($mytext) {
   /\G \s+ /xgc;
   if (/\G ( [\w']+   ) /xgc) { push @tokens, $1; redo; }
   if (/\G ( [^\s\w'] ) /xgc) { push @tokens, $1; redo; }
   die "Bad code";
}
```

But we can simplify that.

```
my @tokens = $mytext =~ /\G\s*([\w']+|[^\S\w'])/g;
```

or even

```
my @tokens = $mytext =~ /\G\s*([\w']+|\S)/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): you want to split (1) on whitespace; (2) whenever the previous character was in `[^\w']` (except at end-of-string); and (3) whenever the next character is in `[^\w']` (except at start-of-string), so you can write:

```
@tokens = split /\s+|(?<=[^\w'])|(?=(?!^)[^\w'])/, $mytext;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perldoc -f split 
==>
    split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT
    split /PATTERN/,EXPR
    split /PATTERN/
    split   Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns that
            list. By default, empty leading fields are preserved, and empty
            trailing ones are deleted. (If all fields are empty, they are
            considered to be trailing.)
    ...
            If the PATTERN contains parentheses, additional list elements
            are created from each matching substring in the delimiter.

                split(/([,-])/, "1-10,20", 3);

            produces the list value

                (1, '-', 10, ',', 20)
    ...
```

ADDED:

In code:

```
my $inp   = 'hi. my name is first_last ...';
my @parts = split /(\W)/, $inp;
printf "%d parts: (%s)\n", scalar @parts, join('), (', @parts);
@parts = grep {$_ gt ' '} @parts;
printf "%d parts: (%s)\n", scalar @parts, join('), (', @parts);
```

output:

```
18 parts: (hi), (.), (), ( ), (my), ( ), (name), ( ), (is), ( ), (first_last), ( ), (), (.), (), (.), (), (.)
9 parts: (hi), (.), (my), (name), (is), (first_last), (.), (.), (.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on ysth's ideas:

```
my $mytext = 'hi. My name22222 is first_last!? 2,0 #@/';
my @tokens = $mytext =~ /([a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+|[.?!,])/g;
print join ":", @tokens,"\n";
```

Output:

```
hi:.:My:name:22222:is:first_last:!:?:2:,:0:
```

This is easier to understand as it avoids the use of \w and \S. \w covers more than you think as it includes _ which is confusing. \S also matches more than just punctuation.

The above shows how you can use | to split the sets of characters that can make up a word and it explicitly defines the characters. The "garbage" that is not part of any word is filtered out.